# Json to CSV in python - Selective Fields

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently getting an HTTP post response from an application which is in JSON and I need to export it into csv. I heard everywhere that I can use pandas, but I didn't find an explanation on how to select the required columns from the JSON.

**Python Code to get the response is below. **

```python
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

**Json Structure in the *response***

```json
{
    'data': {
        'results': [
            {
            'ID': '2023-09-22T00:15:41.015298911Z',
            'cve': 'CVE-2023-27482',
            'cvss': 10,
            'scoreVersion': 'V3'},
            {
            'ID': '2024-01-24T14:12:32.167164571Z',
            'cve': 'CVE-2005-2541',
            'cvss': 10,
            'scoreVersion': 'V2'}
.............
             }
}
```

**Required Structure**

In the csv file, I only need the fields from `ID` onward, just like the following:

```csv
ID,cve,cvss,scoreVersion
2023-09-22T00:15:41.015298911Z,CVE-2023-27482,10,V3
2024-01-24T14:12:32.167164571Z,CVE-2005-2541,10,V2
```

Saving the data into a csv via pandas without modification doesn't work. I've tried using the code below, but each object will be inserted into only one cell. I need, instead, to split into different columns each object's attributes.

```python
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, verify=False)
text_data = response.text
json_dict = json.loads(text_data)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_dict['data'])
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

[image: csv file after the above code]

Comment: Can you edit and add your attempt?

Comment: Just extract the results like `data['results']` before you convert to a pandas data frame? You're getting one cell called "results" in your pandas table (code for that would help) because data has 1 thing in it at that level. You need to go one level further in.

Comment: As @Pam mention, extract `results` first, before using `.from_dict`. And then save it with `.to_csv(path, index=False)`

Comment: Sorry I did not provide the attempts which I did. Now I have updated. Please check back. I have done what you have mentioned. However, the columns are not splitted .

Comment: your `from_dict` should contain `results` instead of `data`. `from_dict(json_dict.get("data", {}).get("results"))`. Remember to use `index=False` on `to_csv` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the json_normalize method:

```py
response_dict = {
    'data': {
        'results': [
            {
            'ID': '2023-09-22T00:15:41.015298911Z',
            'cve': 'CVE-2023-27482',
            'cvss': 10,
            'scoreVersion': 'V3'},
            {
            'ID': '2024-01-24T14:12:32.167164571Z',
            'cve': 'CVE-2005-2541',
            'cvss': 10,
            'scoreVersion': 'V2'}
        ]}}

    pd.json_normalize(response_dict['data'], 'results')
```

[image]

To get the response_dict from the response object just do `json.loads(response.text)`

Comment: Didn't know about `json_normalize`. Good catch.

Comment: Thank you very much. It did it. I was working on this for a whole day. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your `from_dict` should contain `results` instead of `data`.

I recommend extract `results` in a variable to ensure it's not `None`:

```py
# assuming j is the json-parsed dict result
results = j.get("data", {}).get("results"))
if results:
   df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(results)
   df.to_csv("results.csv", index=False)
```